# How to forward emails

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

Is it possible to forward emails from Laravel v5.5? If so, would it be via IMAP or SMTP?

At this point I managed to fetch emails via IMAP. I also know how to create and send out new emails.

Comment: [The Laravel documentation contains an entire section on how to send Emails.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail)

Comment: @Jerodev You are right but there is nothing about forwarding emails...

Comment: If you can fetch and send them, you can forward them combining the 2

Comment: It's the same thing. You already fetched the mails, so no you just have to send them.

Comment: So there is nothing like get the message reference, now forward it... I mean what I was hoping was to avoid hassle with extracting different parts of message along with attachment(s) and creating new email with all of it again ...